# Getting a loading scren to work with Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

I'm trying to get a loading screen to work in Polymer, as seen in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/SlicedSilver/f2e93a5995f84d9cd512

The idea's pretty simple: the entrypoint is a lightweight HTML file that renders the loading screen, whose body contains an onload callback that loads up the Polymer app via the DOM once that lightweight page is rendered.

It works beautifully on desktop browsers. On mobile browsers the filestoload.html is never getting loaded (but also isn't throwing any errors), so the loading screen just stays there and the app never loads. The full code is below, but particular attention goes to this line:

```
tag.setAttribute('onload', 'polymerLoader.insertPolymerApplication()');
```

That onload event never fires and never throws an error. I've tried catching it both through the DOM and with a proper event hander to no avail. I've even tried taking it out of the hands of the JS altogether as a sanity check, adding the link to the HTML file like so:

```
<link rel="import" href="/filestoload.html" onload="polymerLoader.insertPolymerApplication()" >
```

Same result - displays the app on desktop, but just shows the loading screen on mobile. I'm fresh out of ideas. Any help?

....

Here's the lightweight entry point (index.html)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico"/>

    <title>GreenMaven</title>
    <meta name="description" content="greenmaven description">

    <script src="assets/js/polymerAppLoader.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

      .loading {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        /* bring your own prefixes */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        z-index: -500;
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="polymerLoader.loadPolymerApplication()">

    <div id="loader" class="loading">
      <img src="assets/images/gears.svg" />
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the JS that loads the rest of the Polymer app:

```js
'use strict';
/* global polymerLoader */
/*jshint unused:false*/
/*jshint -W079*/


// This is the normal conditional loader for the Web components Polyfill
if ('registerElement' in document && 'createShadowRoot' in HTMLElement.prototype && 'import' in document.createElement('link') && 'content' in document.createElement('template')) {
  // We're using a browser with native WC support!
} else {
  // Add web components polyfill...
  document.write('<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.lite.js"><\/script>');
}

var polymerLoader = (function() {

  // Function for creating a link element and inserting it into the <head> of the html document
  function addLinkTag(elementType, address, shim, loadTrigger) {
    var tag = document.createElement('link');
    tag.rel = elementType;
    tag.href = address;
    if (shim) {
      // add the shim-shadowdom attribute
      tag.setAttribute('shim-shadowdom', '');
    }
    if (loadTrigger) {
      // This file needs to be loaded before inserting the Polymer Application
      // when finished loading it will call the polymerLoader.insertPolymerApplication() function
      tag.setAttribute('onload', 'polymerLoader.insertPolymerApplication()');
      expectedCalls++;
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
  }

  var pgApploaded = false;

  function loadPolymerApplication() {
    // Only insert once.
    if (!pgApploaded) {
      addLinkTag('import', 'filestoload.html', false, true);
      pgApploaded = true;
    }
  }

  // Counter variable for insertPolymerApplication() calls
  var callCount = 0;
  var expectedCalls = 0;

  function insertPolymerApplication() {
    callCount++;
    // Only when callCount >= expectedCalls
    // The application is only inserted after all required files have loaded
    // for the application to work.
    if (callCount >= expectedCalls) {
      // here is the html that is inserted when everything is loaded.
      document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<template is="auto-binding" id="app"><polymer-app id="main-app"></polymer-app></template>';
      document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }


  return {
    insertPolymerApplication: function() {
      insertPolymerApplication();
    },

    loadPolymerApplication: function() {
      loadPolymerApplication();
    }
  };
})(document);
```

And finally, here's the filestoload.html file that has the links and scripts that would usually be found in the Polymer index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- Here is where you put the scripts required by the page, that would normally be -->
<!-- included in the index.html page, you can still use grunt/gulp build functions on these -->

<!-- will be replaced with elements/elements.vulcanized.html -->
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="import" href="/src/greenmaven-app/greenmaven-app.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- endreplace-->

<!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
<script src="properties_base/farmhacker-properties.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild-->

<!-- build:js scripts/thirdparty.js -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - $('#navbar').height()
              }, 1000);
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
<!-- endbuild-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be some kind of bug in the Polymer build, probably related to another error where running `polymer build` was resulting in the app throwing a bunch of 404 errors from bower components.

When I did a raw deployment (without building/vulcanizing) to the server, everything worked fine on both desktop and mobile, and without the errors.